# Persist operations on People API appear to be much slower than on Contacts API

Tags: google-people-api

We have recently switched over to the new Google People API on our sync platform. We chose to only do this for newly set up connections for now so to determine the impact.

Functionally all seems to work fine, so no actual bugs to be raised.
However we noticed that the performance of the People API seems to be much lower compared to the Contacts API.
More specifically we saw the following differences when summarising all requests of today:

- Creation response time: 571 ms (versus 201 ms on the old Contacts API)
- Update response time: 735 ms (versus 168 ms on the old Contacts API)

There are also differences in the other operations, but especially the difference in the response time of persists is clear. Even more, the batch persist operation on the old Contacts API was going faster on average (we use a batch size of up to 30 records) than a single create/update operation on the People API.

Is this something that can be improved in the near future?
It is not really blocking our end users, but it does lead to degraded sync performance. Especially users with large contact sets will experience significantly longer syncing times (as we are syncing all historical contact data).

If you like, I can provide you with some example API requests and response calls.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not coding related.

Comment: @ziganotschka On the Google People API support page (https://developers.google.com/people/support) this location is explicitly mentioned as the sole reference to ask "technical questions". 
I believe this qualifies for that purpose. I'm happy to ask this question on another location if you can point it out to me.

Comment: An interesting post and I also am interested to see the responses to this. I think that Super User (https://superuser.com/) would be a better stack exchange forum to raise this on.

Comment: @Clinton thank you for this suggestion!
I'll post it on superuser.com as well.

I also hope that this gets picked up and I get some response here. Would you mind upvoting my question so it gets a bit more visibility, please?

Comment: @WoutDeGeyter have you heard anything from Google on this? Is there a BATCH Update/Create method like there was on Google Contacts?

Comment: @user1112324 No, I unfortunately have not. If you would have other ways to raise this, I would be very happy to hear so...
They didn't have any batch create/update the last time we checked (only a batch get). But as mentioned in my above post, the batch persist on the old Contacts API was faster than a single persist on the new API. This is not hopeful for the upcoming availability of a batch persist method ...

Comment: I do have some contacts there who could probably connect me with the right people. Ill try to reach out when I can